# Tooltipster arrow on and content to be on left

Tags: jquery, css, tooltipster

I'm using this jQuery plugin called Tooltipster (https://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#options). Is it possible to open the content and arrow on the left side? I've been reading their documentation and it seems that I can't get it working. Any help is much appreciated! Here's my code:

HTML

```
<span class="tooltip" title="Test Content Here">
     <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span>
```

JS

```
$('.tooltip').tooltipster({
     theme: 'tooltipster-shadow',
     trigger: 'click',
     position: 'bottom'
});
```

I'm getting this output:

[image]

But I would really like to get this output:

[image]

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this issue by using 'bottom-left' on 'position' property name.

```
$('.tooltip').tooltipster({
     theme: 'tooltipster-shadow',
     trigger: 'click',
     position: 'bottom-left'
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I Read the options and I think you can move the tooltip. Modify your code in this way:

```
$('.tooltip').tooltipster({
     theme: 'tooltipster-shadow',
     trigger: 'click',
     position: 'bottom',
     side:'left'
});
```

I think it migth work.

Comment: Thank you sir for answering. I've tried this approach already but it's not working. But I've solved this problem now. Thank you!